# Application fails on webserver completely while running fine on localhost

Tags: php

I'm currently in the progress of developing a little web application. So far all my testing has been done on localhost for convenience.
With everything major implemented I wanted to jump ship and test things on a webserver now and what I noticed is that, while the application runs on localhost just fine I get thrown a ton of weird errors when I open up the deployed server version.

Both servers run on PHP 8.0.0 so version differences shouldn't be the problem here.
The only major difference should be that my local machine is Windows based while, as far as I know, the server runs on Linux.

An example of the errors that get thrown on the webserver are the following

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token ";", expecting "function" or "const" in [...]/User.class.php on line 1
```

While said User.class.php looks like this

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING ^ E_NOTICE);
    require_once "autoloader.php";
    require_once dirname(__FILE__)."/../libs/DateTools.php";
    require_once dirname(__FILE__)."/../libs/StringTools.php";

class User extends DBConnect
{
    private $pkuser;
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Check line feeds that they match system line feeds. Maybe error is somewhere else and all your code on Linux is in one line?

Comment: @Justinas That happened to be the problem, apparently. After uploading the files again with the correct line feeds I don't even get any errors anymore.